# SDR implementation on FPGA

Tags: fpga, gnuradio, uhd

I have an altera DE2 cyclone-ii fpga board and I want to implement a project on software defined radio(SDR) using GNU Radio on it.Is it possible to load USRP Hardware Driver(FPGA build) provided by Ettus Research.If possible how can I do it.If not is there any other way to implement SDR on FPGA :)

Comment: you're confusing all: What GNU Radio is, what an FPGA is, and what UHD does. No, none of this works like you seem to think it does.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will need some daughter boards to do the front-end processing, which handles the high-frequency signals.

You can use an [RTL](https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/32939551915.html?src=google&src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=494-037-6276&isdl=y&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Gploogle_7_shopping&aff_atform=google&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&&albagn=888888&albcp=7303158455&albag=86143156931&trgt=883147839819&crea=pt32939551915&netw=u&device=c&albpg=883147839819&albpd=pt32939551915&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI86izzpLI6QIVDAyRCh0mtgROEAQYASABEgKOQfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) as a daughter board and with some changes at the USRP code (mostly on the signal reception) you will be able to build your own SDR.